# HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE for all users, no Virtual Store

Tags: registry, virtualstore

I have an application that has some settings in the registry that I only want the administrator, or administrator privileges to update them. As of right now, I have it on HKLM, but if I open the application as a regular user it goes over to its VirtualStore HKCU/../../VirtualSture instead of HKLM/Software/AppName/..

Is there a way to change this? Or is there a work-around?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it only happens on legacy applications. My fix was manually remove the VirtualStore/AppName and it fixed the problem.

Thanks